# Truth Teller and Liar Problem

Tags: logic

I am finding it very confusing. Please help understand how to answer the question.

Ram says " if 23 is even, then i am a truth teller"

Shyam says "Ram is a liar"

Now, how to solve this problem?

Since 23 is not an even number, this suggests Ram is a liar, now this implies, Shyam is a Truth teller. But if Ram is liar, how come he is telling the truth that "I am a liar"?

Answer is inconclusive or what?

Comment: "But if Ram is liar, how come he is telling the truth that "I am a liar"?" This suggests to me that you're interpreting "if" in Ram's statement as "if *and only if*." But that's incorrect: "if" is only one way, and "If A then B" is automatically **true** whenever $A$ is false.

Comment: This is something new to me -> "if A then B" is automatically true if A is false. Can u suggest any tutorial?

Answer (score 3):

A false statement implies anything.  Since "$23$ is even" is false, Ram is telling the truth.  So Shyam is telling a lie.

Comment: A false statement implies anything? does that mean it can imply both True and False? i did not get it.

Comment: @RajeshK.Pandey The statements $P,Q$ have 4 possibilities: either $P$ is true or it is false, and either $Q$ is true or it is false.  Of these 4 possibilities, the only one that makes the statement (if $P$ then $Q$) false is if $P$ is true and $Q$ is false.  The other 3 possibilites for $P,Q$ all render the statement (if $P$ then $Q$) a true statement.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Robert's excellent answer (+1), this problem is an application of the principle of vacuous truth:

$~~~~~~~\neg A \implies (A \implies B)~$ regardless of the truth value of $B$

It can be proven using a truth table:

[image]

Source: https://www.erpelstolz.at/gateway/TruthTable.html

Note that, whatever the truth value of $A$ may be, this principle cannot be used to determine the truth value of $B$ here. If $A$ is true (lines 1-2), then $B$ could be either true or false. Likewise if $A$ false (lines 3-4).

This principle can also be formally proven using a form of natural deduction. It uses proof by contradiction (line 5) and elimination of double negation (line 6):

(screen shot from my proof checker)

[image]